# Wrong Code In C# Via CLR Book

Tags: c#

I am reading this book and am stuck here:

```
public static class EventArgExtensions { 
   public static void Raise<TEventArgs>(this TEventArgs e,  
      Object sender, ref EventHandler<TEventArgs> eventDelegate)  
      where TEventArgs : EventArgs { 

      // Copy a reference to the delegate field now into a temporary field for thread safety  
      EventHandler<TEventArgs> temp =  
         Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref eventDelegate, null, null); 

      // If any methods registered interest with our event, notify them   
      if (temp ! = null) temp(sender, e); 
   } 
}
```

Specifically the MSDN doc says that

> ```
> public static object CompareExchange(ref object location1, object value, object comparand)
> ```
>
> Member of System.Threading.Interlocked
>
> **Summary:**
>   Compares two objects for reference equality and, if they are equal, replaces one of the objects.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   *location1*: The destination object that is compared with comparand and possibly replaced.
>   *value*: The object that replaces the destination object if the comparison results in equality.
>   *comparand*: The object that is compared to the object at location1.
>
> **Returns:**
>   The original value in location1.
>
> **Exceptions:**
>   System.ArgumentNullException: The address of location1 is a null pointer.

which means that this is wrong :

```
 EventHandler<TEventArgs> temp =  
             Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref eventDelegate, null, null); 

          // If any methods registered interest with our event, notify them   
          if (temp ! = null) temp(sender, e);
```

because I need to be checking what was **passed** in to CompareExchange and not the output.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

No, the code is fine. It's effectively just a way of performing a volatile read. It will only return null if it replaced null with null - i.e. if `eventDelegate` is null.